# Filter multi-dimenisonal array jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, filter

I have a plugin (https://github.com/bjorn2404/jQuery-Store-Locator-Plugin) that creates a multidimensional array with the code:

```
locationset[i] = new Array (distance, name, lat, lng, address, address2, city, state, postal, phone, web, hours1, hours2, hours3);
i++;
```

I need to filter it based on distance (let's say it should be less than 10).

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: use [jQuery.grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var filtered_array = $.grep(locationset, function(value) { 
    return value[0] < 10;
});
```

You should use [grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/), because that's what it was designed for.